# Magento1.9 - Pass multiple variables to block with SetData

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

In a template I currently have the following working code:

```
$sticazzi = 'hey Frank';
$this->getChild('child-name')->setData("sticazzi", $sticazzi);
echo $this->getChildHtml('child-name');
```

and then in my block:

```
$sticazzi = $this->getData('sticazzi');
echo '<h1>' . $sticazzi . '</h1>';
```

This will render `hey Frank` in the template.

How can I pass multiple variables to the block in the same way? Does setData accept an array of vars? Is there a better way to do this (I would prefer not to use xml layout in this case).

Comment: You can set array variable or an object using the same code and can get data the same way.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense; btw, is there a way to do it in a more explicit way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setData()` function need to set just **one value** on one call.

1. You can use `addData()` to set a multiple data with an array like this:
   `$obj->addData(array('k1'=>'v1', 'k2'=>'v2'))`

2)You can do it in xml layout

```
<action method="setData"><name>sticazzi</name><value>hey Frank</value></action>
<action method="setData"><name>sticazzi2</name><value>hey Franky</value></action>
```

Then you get it like this:

```
$this->getData('sticazzi');
$this->getData('sticazzi2');
```